# Laravel Echo is not receiving event from pusher

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In my Pusher console the events are there but the response back to my browser is not working.

This is my echo code:

```
Echo.private('Review.'+this.bookId)
    .listen('BroadcastComment', (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: I use Pusher but without Echo so I might be wrong, but is the `.` in front of `.App\...` really correct?  [None of the examples in the docs use that syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#using-example-application), nor do any examples I can find elsewhere online.

Comment: `Echo.private('Review.'+this.bookId)
    .listen('.App\Event\BroadcastComment', (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });`


    `Echo.private('Review.'+this.bookId)
    .listen('App\Event\BroadcastComment', (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });`




    `Echo.private('Review.'+this.bookId)
    .listen('BroadcastComment', (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });`


these are the three options that I have tried, and none of them is working

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, apparently, Echo does not  work in the Vue created lifecycle but it does in the mounted lifecycle